# How make api calls in a chrome extension with MV3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to migrate my chrome extension from MV2 - MV3, The app makes several API calls. When I build and install the extension locally it works fine but when I test the published version of the app... It doesn't make any internet connection. The extension is built using reactJS + parcel v1

Has anyone also faced these issues before, I cannot tell what I am doing wrong?

Here's is my the log of the error I am getting [image]

In the `manifest.json` I set the `host_permission` like so

```
 }
  ...
 "host_permissions": [
"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall",
"https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/",
"https://type.fit/api/quotes",
"http://ip-api.com/json"
]

...
}
```

Comment: Add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question i.e. the code that makes the request and how that code is declared/executed.

Comment: perhaps share the code where you are making those calls. and share you manifest. i moved my code to service worker and able to make fetch calls no problem.